Confuse about the way import module on Deno project
As far as I know there are 4 ways of import module in Deno project:

deno.land/x
esm.sh
jsr
npm

And I guess the priority order would be just like how I list them above? I mean deno official recommend using deno.land rather than esm.sh, esm.sh would be a better choice than jsr.
Suppose I was right, here is the confusing part when I try to install Hono and its CORS middleware.

I can find Hono framework both on NPM and deno.land, but I cannot find ExpressJS on deno.land by searching on this page. What’s the standard of deno.land including the third party modules? I assume ExpressJS is popular among the NodeJS community.
Suppose esm.sh is the second best way to import modules because they should include all standard ES modules. However, I cannot find the appropriate way to import Hono CORS middleware via esm.sh.

This is the way show on official site about how to introduce on deno.land
import { cors } from 'https://deno.land/x/hono/middleware.ts'. 

But I cannot find the module on esm.sh:
https://esm.sh/hono@4.3.8/middleware 


What’s purpose of JSR? I cannot find either Hono nor ExpressJS on the website.


Deno supports importing standard JavaScript modules, and also includes compatibility support for node:, npm:, and jsr: specifiers. I expect that the information at Why JSR? will clear things up for you… but it's not clear to me what's actually being asked in the question. You can edit it to clarify the single, direct question.


And I guess the priority order would be just like how I list them above?

I would argue it is actually (reasons in parentheses):

npm (defacto registry most javascript modules are published to)
esm.sh (defaults to npm as registry, but also supports GitHub and jsr)
jsr (superset of npm)
deno.land (some new thing specific to deno)


I cannot find ExpressJS on deno.land

Did you try entering "express" in the search box? Check out this URL: https://deno.land/x?query=express. There you will see https://deno.land/x/express@v0.0.0. However, I probably wouldn't use that, but instead import express from "npm:express@4.18.2"; as mentioned in How to use Express with Deno. Yet another reason why importing from deno.land is last in my priority order.

I cannot find the appropriate way to import Hono CORS middleware via esm.sh

If you look at the exports field of the package.json file for hono, you will see they provide a subpath export of /cors that you can use.
import { cors } from 'https://esm.sh/hono@4.3.9/cors'


What's purpose of JSR?


https://jsr.io/docs/why
https://jsr.io/docs/using-packages#native-jsr-imports

Regarding hono on the jsr registry there is this: https://jsr.io/@hono/do-not-use-this. Obviously you shouldn’t use that but the package appears to be attempting to figure out the best way to publish to jsr.
For express and hono you are better off using imports from npm or esm.sh.
